# Forcing a certain width/height with overflow in a <td>

Tags: html, css

I have a `<table>` with `table-layout` set to *fixed*, so that all explicit width/height definitions are respected no matter what. I'm trying to get a certain `<td>` to overflow, but even though I did the `table-layout: fixed` it doesn't work.

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: What do you mean by overflow exactly? What does the td contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work because the `<td>` will always have the size of an image

---

You can use height and width attributes. If the image size is 400x300, typing `<img src="..." height="100" width="100" />` will show 100x100 image

If you want to crop an image use

```
<style>
#id{
background:url(...) no-repeat; /* you can use background-position css property here... */
height:100px;
width:100px;
</style>
<div id="image"></div>
```

Comment: Can I make the image float to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `table-layout: fixed`, you can only guarantee the column widths, not heights. Also, the content of cells has no bearing on those widths. From [w3schools:](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_tab_table-layout.asp)

> The horizontal layout only depends on
>   the table's width and the width of the
>   columns, not the contents of the cells.

How much control do you need over the individual cells? Are you going for hidden overflow or one that can scroll? It's not clear from your question.