# How to force a TD to be a certain height with CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Although [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124630/forcing-a-certain-width-height-with-overflow-in-a-td) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968561/overflow-auto-in-table-td-that-has-no-certain-height) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091179/css-how-to-make-td-a-fixed-height) to this one have been asked before, this one is a little different.

I have a table that looks a little something like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td style="height: 100px;">
   <img src="..." style="height: 100px;" />
   <img src="..." style="height: 100px; position: relative; top: -100px;" />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

This will overlay the second image on the first one. **However,** the `td` insists on being `200px` tall *even though there is only `100px` of content*. Setting the `td`'s height does nothing, which seems consistent with the answers to the other questions.

However, I do not have the option of embedding the contents in a `DIV` and setting the height to `100px` because the `td` will **still** insist on being `200px` tall.

How can I tell the `td` to *just be `100px` tall?*

---

**Edit:** Oh, and using absolute positioning is out of the question too because a lot of DOM manipulation goes on in the page and stuff gets moved around - whereas the absolutely positioned stuff does not.

---

**Edit:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example [can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/S3s4G/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `td` really, but with the nature of `position: relative`. A relative element's space stays reserved in the document flow.

Get rid of the `relative`, and use `position: absolute` on the first image instead.

**Edit: I** just saw your edit. Hmmm. Thinking.

Two workaround ideas come to mind:

- Slap a `overflow: hidden` on the `td`
- If that doesn't work in all browsers or isn't valid (I'm not 100% sure  right now) Put the two images into a `<div height='100px;'>` and put a `overflow: hidden` on that.

Comment: @George I added a workaround that should work - if it's compatible with your DOM manipulations

Comment: @Pekka: The first solution doesn't work (not in Chrome at least), and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the second one: where does `overflow: hidden` go?

Answer (score 0):

Declaring

```
<td style="height: 100px; width:100px; overflow:hidden"> ...
```

should help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It doesn't get rid of the space.

Answer (score 0):

Overlay a second image in a table cell:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    table {border:1px solid #898989;}
    td {border:1px solid #0090aa; overflow:hidden; height: 100px;}
    td div {position:relative;}
    .col1 {width:80px;}
    .col1 {width:128px;}
    .over {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; }
    .under {}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">1</td>
            <td>
                <div>
                   <img class="under" src="blank_file.png"  />
                   <img class="over" src="19.png"  />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is 200px of content because `position:relative` does not free up the space the object occupied before it was moved. You NEED to use position absolute and probably an inner DIV because things like overflow tend to cause issues on TD's.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using position relative on the second image to move it up and overlay, use negative margin.

Change this.

```
<img src="..." style="height: 100px; position: relative; top: -100px;" />
```

Use:

```
<img src="..." style="height: 100px; margin-top:-100px" />
```

That way, it'll actually move the image up and that TD will then only span 100px.