# Force div height 0 regardless of child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a `tr` within a `table`. onClick it appends some `html`. I'm trying to make the `tr` it appends transition nicely, so I'm trying to set the height to 0, then onClick set it to auto.

However, my div isn't taking height 0. I can add `height: 0;` but it still keeps the height.

My HTML:

```
<tr class="info_container">  
    <td colspan="7">Pick a time
        <button id="time_btn">Button</button>
        <span class="tickets_left_cont"> 7 tickets left</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.info_container {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    z-index: 999;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: BreeSerifLt;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}

#time_btn {
    outline: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #9A0FC7;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: BreeSerifLt;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I make `info_container` class height `0` so it hides the div?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the table column width constant regardless of the amount of text in its cells?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text-in-its-cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On tables, `height` and `width` behave as `min-height` and `min-width`

Comment: Oh thanks man, I wasn't aware of that. So i'd need to use `max-height` whenever I want to change the height of an element within a table?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286747/how-to-force-a-td-to-be-a-certain-height-with-css